# Suggestion on using UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a set of pictures organized by name like below which indicates where a photo should be in the view:

Image_PPRRCC.png

PP: Page No. of photo

RR: Row of photo

CC: Column of photo

The app has three kind of views as below.

1- View the whole page. Scroll horizontally to view next page. 
[image: whole page view]

2- Single image view. When user has double tapped on a picture in whole page view. Scroll horizontally to next photo. 
[image: single photo view]

3- View a row of photos. When device is in landscape mode. Scroll vertically to view next row and scroll horizontally to view next page. 
[image: row view]

I tried using a `UICollectionViewController` and put the images in dynamically sized cells sorted by their names. The problem was with horizontal scrolling. When horizontal scrolling is selected the items are populated vertically in a `UICollectionView` and the sorted array of image names and position of each photo in row and column of a page is messed up.

Then tried to use a `UIPageViewController` with a `UIView` for each page with a `UICollectionView` in each page to show images of corresponding page. But I couldn't manage to setup the views for it. 
So any suggestions how to setup the views? Which method is better for the desired interface of the app? The one `UICollectionViewController` method or `UIPageViewController` method? Or maybe a better method?

Comment: I like your `UIDoodleCollectionViewController` =]

Answer (score 0):

use @property (nonatomic) UICollectionViewScrollDirection scrollDirection;

The grid layout scrolls along one axis only, either horizontally or vertically. For the non scrolling axis, the width of the collection view in that dimension serves as starting width of the content.

read more about UICollectionViewFlowLayout in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012182-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4

Comment: So it seems I have to stick with UIPageViewController method and scroll vertically in UICollectionView and scroll horizontally in UIPageView for row view.